# how to write elastic aggregation to plot VM's CPU % usages on grafana?

Tags: logstash, grafana, elasticsearch-aggregation, libvirt, collectd

I am trying to plot VM's CUP % usages graph on grafana but do not able to figure out aggregation query.

I have setup collectd with virt plugin to fetch VM's metrics and storing it into elastic search via logstash.

I tried to fetch [result](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=15ad83e6d8064c57b73a7183bbe83fb7) by [a simple query](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=bec133d1f6614bbfb60426c9f4568c0a) and it is working.

But I could not able to figure out aggregation query to plot this data on grafana.

I tried it to do with the count. [here it's xhr response](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=fd1bd09c606643dcacb98552132a5679)
But it is plotting doc_count.

[grafana query editor image link](https://s.nimbusweb.me/attachment/2786664/am57dhby6oo9lo3xv622/ZnAPNWgGI18isFvh/screenshot-104.255.99.66-3000-2019.04.19-01-45-27.png)